# Ferrite bead for low frequencies

Tags: emc, ferrite-bead

I have a circuit where there is a high level of noise at 100 kHz. For now, I'm not allowed to rework the circuit. I wanted to use a ferrite core, but when I look at the impedance characteristics chart, they all start from 300 kHz.

What would you recommend to start with?

Comment: Are there any operational, functional or performance issues that you are unhappy with? If yes, do you think these are to do with the noise? Is it noise or is it a regular signal that is normally produced by the circuit when performing its duties?

Comment: Can you just use a 1-2Ohm resistor combined with the existing capacitance in the circuit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though a ferrite bead only becomes lossy above some frequency, it's still inductive down to DC. The inductance is rarely specified, but you can calculate it from the slope of the impedance graph in the specification.

As it's inductive, you can design a CLC pi filter with one.